# Аналоги ulogin, Loginza международные?

Tags: javascript, auth, ulogin

Есть ли иностранные аналоги систем аутентификации, чтобы поддерживали много разных международных систем и могли 
выводить текст и предпочитаемые системы для пользователя с учетом страны, на разных языках?

То есть для россии vk, mail, однокласники будет предлагать на русском, для Китая свои соц сети и.т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть на эти системы:

- http://www.loginradius.com/social-login
- http://janrain.com/product/social-login